# how to set number input in alerttextfield 20 to 20000 number swift?

Tags: ios, swift3

```
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Interval Mode", message: "Please input 20 to 20000 ms", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: .default) { (_) in

        let txtMiliSecond = alertController.textFields?[0]
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (_) in }

    alertController.addTextField {
            (textField) in textField.placeholder = "Enter 20 to 20000 ms";
            textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
    }
```

Comment: whenever the text is edited, see if it is within the range, if it is not, then show an error.

Comment: add the condition like `let inte = CInt(txtMiliSecond.text!)
        if inte! < 20001 && inte! > 19 {
            // do your stuff
        }
        else {
           // show the alert again        }`

Comment: i need to enter only 20 to 20000 milisecond in alert view textfiled.

Comment: The answer given by @RJiryes seems to be the most feasible solution for the requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn 
   range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if(textField.tag == 1 && self.isDigit(string) == true){

        let maxLength = 5

        let newLength = (textField.text?.characters.count)! + 
          string.characters.count - range.length

        return newLength <= maxLength
    }

    else if (textField.tag == 2){

        let maxLength = 16

        guard let text = textField.text
            else{
            return true
        }

        let newLength = text.characters.count + 
         string.characters.count - range.length

        return newLength <= maxLength
    }
    return false
}
```

set tag number to text field.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a target to when the text changes in the text field

```
 alertController.addTextField { (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = "Enter Reason"
        textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
        self.saveAction.isEnabled = false
    }
```

And then, do something when the text field changes.

```
 func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if(textField.text?.isEmpty == true){
        //Disable Button
        saveAction.isEnabled = false
    }else{
        //Enable button
        saveAction.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

In this example I enable/disable save button based on the textfield